# Volley request always get Error Listener

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

```
  JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) 
    {
        try {
            JSONArray images = response.getJSONArray("images");
            for(int i = 0; i<images.length(); i++)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj =(JSONObject)images.get(i);

                    //JSONObject obj = images.getJSONObject(i);
                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                    movie.setTitle(obj.getString("itemid"));
                    movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("imagepath"));
                    movieList.add(movie);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {


        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    };

        } 
        , new Response.ErrorListener(

                ) {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in Json parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        hidePDialog();
                    }
        });
```

**JSON part:**

```
{ 
"images": 
{ 
"imageid":"1",
"itemid":"item1",
"imagepath":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/resturant\/image\/chinese1.jpg"
},
{ 
"imageid":"2",
"itemid":"item2",
"imagepath":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/resturant\/image\/chinese2.jpg"
}
]
}
```

Here I want to retrieve itemid and imagepath tag from images JSON array. But my JSON is not resopnding and it's showing the toast of error listener. Can anybody help, please? I take permission of Internet and I check the URL and it's working.

Comment: How would we know, you havent even posted the message from VolleyError object

Comment: the message in log cat from volley is          01-08 03:26:06.208: D/Volley(1781): [1] Request.finish: 11946 ms: [ ] http://127.0.0.1/resturant/connection.php 0x59c3b57d NORMAL 1

Comment: Can you open `127.0.0.1/resturant/connection.php` from your mobile browser ?

Comment: Propably request is timing out. Have you tried `Log.e("err", error.getMessage());` in **onErrorResponse**?

Comment: the url is in local host so that i m testing from emulator and in my pc i can access this url and it gives me json data in my code mentioned @Saeed

Comment: i use VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage()); in onErrorresponse and in logcat i find
 01-08 04:33:18.748: D/Volley(1998): [1] 2.onErrorResponse: MainActivity   can you explain what does it mean?? @vilpe89

Comment: Hi, VolleyErrors are usual Exeptions, so just print them like `error.printStacktrace()`. It usually wraps other exceptions in it like ECONNECTIONREFUSED or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show the content of the `url` you are calling. If your URL contains `127.0.0.1` your are calling the local host of the android emulator (and your server does not run on the emulator).

To call the localhost of your PC from the emulator you must replace `127.0.0.1` by `10.0.2.2`